# How can I accessing a static variable in program P from dlopen'd library L?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have a library (L) that is dynamically loaded by a program (P) using dlopen.  L implements a plugin interface and so calls back on it's parent to obtain some functionality.

Inside P is a singleton object that dynamically creates a thread pool object A.
I need access to A from L.

However, because the singleton works by using a static variable, when L is loaded it ends up creatng it's own instance which is some cases would be fine but I want the instance that was created in P.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: You have several instances of a singleton object? Fix that defect then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have a `static` A in L. Let P pass the address of A to L, i.e., `L.init(&A)`.

Answer (score 1):

File scope names declared `static` have internal linkage. Internal linkage means that they are invisible to other translation units, even in a "classic" linking model without any dynamic libraries. Given that statics are not visible even to other translation units in the same executable, it is not reasonable to expect them to be visible from attached dynamic libraries.

You have to think of a way to achieve the necessary linkage using external, dynamic symbols. Perhaps the singleton simply cannot have an internal name, but must have an external name.

L is creating its own instance of the object not just because the object is static, but because you have linked into L the thread pool module which defines that singleton and the thread pool functions. This can happen even with objects that have external names, depending on how the library is linked.

You must pick a single object in which the thread pool service will reside, and then make sure it only resides there.  Doesn't your project have a utility library where you can stick in this sort of thing?

You *can* adhere to the model that it is the program executable P which provides the thread pool API. This is really the same thing. The program P is another dynamic object and effectively serves as the library for the thread pool module, which it provides to itself and to other shared objects.

Regardless of where that thread pool module lives, make sure that you are not statically linking copies of that module into other objects: it lives just in one place.

If the thread pool singleton's external name is part of that API (everyone knows its documented name and uses it directly, passing that global pool to the API functions) then that name should be made external, and declared in the header file.

If the singleton is to be private, then you have to think of some way of hiding it, like making it implicit in the function calls (there is only one thread pool, and that is that) or else abstracting the access to it somewhat (provide an `ensure_thread_pool`) function which creates a thread pool if one does not exist, or else returns the previously created one, in a thread safe way.

Think: why do not, for instance, `stdin` and `stdout` have this problem? Why doesn't every library instantiate its own `stdout` stream and call its own `fprintf` function on that stream? Why, obviously, because these things live in one place: the C library. Copies of them do not live in other places; other places just use them by reference via the dynamic symbols.